# Updating a state array incrementally as opposed to entirely

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-state

I am fairly new to React and I am just getting my head around using hooks especially useEffect:

````
```const Upload= ({  uploadedCard, cards}) => 
 {useEffect(() => {
cards.push(uploadedCard);
 }, [uploadedCard]); };```
````

Basically every time the uploadedCard is returned from by axios api, I want the cards state to add this new card  to it. Note that cards is an array and thus I want this array to add the new card as opposed to loading all cards at once (which my current approach does):

```
useEffect(() => {
   getAllCards();
  }, [uploadedCard]);
```

Note in the second piece of code that when I call getAllCards() to my backend using React-redux reducers, it automatically returns the 'cards' array as a payload and so my 2nd approach works perfectly but it also causes the 'cards' to render from beginning. Any help on how to circumvent this problem is highly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the cards in a local state in the first place. Then, useEffect will run every time the Upload component receives a different uploadedCard, adding it to the array of cards

```
const Upload= ({ uploadedCard, cards }) => {
  const [ allCards, setAllCards ] = useState(cards);
   useEffect(() => {
   setAllCards([ ...cards, uploadedCard]);
  }, [ uploadedCard ]); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @luismendes535. I tried that by component won't render because the 'cards' state renders as a prop in a different file. I am not sure if I am being efficient here (forgive me as I am new to stackoverflow) but I wanted separate files for the rendered 'cards'  and uploaded card formdata. This is the parent functional component called Update.js:

Comment: `<TabPanel className="tab-pane">
          <div>
            <FileUpload />
          </div>
          <div className="cardGallery">
            <GameCards />
          </div>
        </TabPanel>`

The fileupload component has the above useEffect hook while the GameCard component simply renders the 'cards' state as images:
` const loadCards = () =>{
  var allCards = [];
    cards.forEach((item, i) => {
        allCards.push(<img key={item._id} src={item.src} alt="No file" />);
      });
return allCards;
} 
<div className="cardgallery">{loadCards()}</div>